# Better background masking with imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I found this nice code :
https://phpimagick.com/Tutorial/backgroundMasking 
But I get the same picture without checkerboard. Something is wrong in my config or in the code ?

My best working code is :

```php
  $BackgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
  $img = new Imagick();
  $img->readImage('xxxxx.jpg');
  $img->setImageFormat('png'); 
  $fuzz = Imagick::getQuantum() * 0.1; // 10%
  $img->transparentPaintImage($BackgroundColor,0,$fuzz,false);
  $img->writeImage('xxxx.png');
```

But without blur and mask :(

Any idea ?

Comment: Checkerboard is only to demonstrate the background is alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe there is a better way but just remove this line works for me :)

`$mask->setImageAlphaChannel(\Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE);`